# Multiple treatment timings and intensities Difference-in-Difference model

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, generalized-did

I have a question regarding the Difference-in-Difference model. My data consists of three groups: control, intensity 1 and intensity 2. Both treatment groups have two moments of treatment, essentially creating four treatment groups (five including Control) and four periods (see table)

| Group | Period | Treat * Post |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

I have done a staggered analysis for each intensity group, but I want to run a single regression model to test the difference in intensity. My biggest problem is that the periods are not of the same size, so I have decided to split the fixed effects in individual time and group dummies (is this correct?). This results in the equation:
$$ Y_{it} = \alpha_{1} Time_{2}+\alpha_{2} Time_{3}+\alpha_{3} Time_{4}+\delta _{1}(Treat_{i}^{1}\cdot Post)+\delta _{2}(Treat_{i}^{2}\cdot Post)+\delta _{3}(Treat_{i}^{3}\cdot Post)+\delta _{4}(Treat_{i}^{4}\cdot Post)+X_{it}+\upsilon_{it}$$

My plan is to weigh the effects based on period size, because a single DiD estimator will not account for differences in weights. However, I still feel like I am missing dummies or interactions. I thought that creating individual interactions will replace the group fixed effects, but now it looks like I have four DiD interactions. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Welcome. Does one group receive treatment 1 and a completely separate group receive treatment 2? Also, when you say intensity, do you mean it in a categorical sense (i.e., high/low)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the groups are completely seperate, there are no overlapping units. And yes, the intensity is categorical. However, I've seen in other discussions that it might be important to note that the categories are not mutually exclusive (my hypothesis tests if the high intensity treatment actually has a bigger effect on the dependent variable). In other words, groups 1 and 2 receive a treatment of 'A' and groups 3 and 4 receive 'A+B'.

Comment: And to be clear, do the post-periods vary across units? If they do, then the standard interaction terms aren’t going to cut it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. The post-periods are the same size for units in the same group, but not when comparing groups. So group 1 has a post-treatment period of 143, group 2 of 84 etc.. I figured that the interaction terms would only work if they were seperated by group because of this period difference.

Comment: And lastly, could you please explain what you mean when you say the treatment groups have two “moments” of treatment?

Comment: Half of the low intensity group (A) will receive it August 10th (subgroup 1) and the other half October 8th (subgroup 2)(timeframe is July 20th until December 31st). The other group (high intensity: A+B) will be treated August 10th (subgroup 3) or September 2 (subgroup 4). If a group has been treated, it will stay treated during the rest of the timeframe. The groups are all of equal size.